# How do I write the square of covariance?

Tags: statistics, notation, covariance

Should it be $\mathrm{cov}^{2}(X,Y)$ or should it be $\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)^2$ or $(\mathrm{cov}(X,Y))^2$ or something completely different?

Thank you.

Comment: If in doubt, the latter is least ambiguous.

Comment: Hm I see! I guess I will stick to the last one if I can't find the answer! Because none of the websites out there have anything about square of covariance; which is shocking considering how often it is used in calculating the correlation coefficient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that
$$\mathrm{cov}^2\left(X, Y\right)=\left(\mathrm{cov}\left(X, Y\right)\right)^2$$
Since the exponent is not equal to $-1$ then your okay with writing
$$\mathrm{cov}^2\left(X, Y\right)$$
However, if the exponent was $-1$ then I'd recommend the following
$$\left(\mathrm{cov}\left(X, Y\right)\right)^{-1}$$
This avoids any ambiguity between the inverse of $\mathrm{cov}$ and the multiplicative inverse of $\mathrm{cov}$.

Comment: Hm I see! thank you for helping me out!